# Как заменить текст после символа

Tags: cmd

Есть число `316.243`. Стоит задача в том чтобы убрать все после точки. Должно получиться число `316`. У меня есть регулярка `.\d+$`  но не пойму как применить её к строке

Comment: А тег `cmd` тут вообще каким боком? и язык программирования бы указать неплохо...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для [bat](/questions/tagged/bat) можно так (просто для командной строки - не подойдёт):

```
set x=316.243
call :fn %x%
exit /b

:fn
echo %~n1
exit /b
```

[image: скриншот]